# Want a regular expression to print the output like server name and job name with out paranthesis:

Tags: python, python-re

Below is my code:

```
import re

txt="""
    Line 677: 05/01/2023 05:38:46 Windows OS backup of test226693 (test.env.dev.os.wn.sev.test226693.ep2) succeeded
    Line 683: 05/01/2023 05:38:46 Windows OS backup of test226745 (test.env.dev.os.wn.sev.test226745.ep2) succeeded
    Line 689: 05/01/2023 05:38:46 Windows OS backup of test226825 (test.env.dev.os.wn.sev.test226825.ep2) succeeded
    Line 695: 05/01/2023 05:38:46 Windows OS backup of test226889 (test.env.dev.os.wn.sev.test226889.ep2) succeeded
    Line 701: 05/01/2023 05:38:46 Windows OS backup of test227082 (test.env.dev.os.wn.sev.test227082.ep2) succeeded
    Line 707: 05/01/2023 05:38:46 Windows OS backup of test227102 (test.env.dev.os.wn.sev.test227102.ep2) succeeded
    Line 713: 05/01/2023 05:38:46 Windows OS backup of test227159 (test.env.dev.os.wn.sev.test227159.ep2) succeeded
    Line 719: 05/01/2023 05:38:46 Windows OS backup of test227203 (test.env.dev.os.wn.sev.test227203.ep2) succeeded
    """
    pattern=re.compile(r'of(\s\w+\s\(.*?\))')
    res=pattern.findall(txt)
    for i in res:
        print(i)
```

Below is my output for the above code..

test226693 (test.env.dev.os.wn.sev.test226693.ep2)

test226745 (test.env.dev.os.wn.sev.test226745.ep2)

test226825 (test.env.dev.os.wn.sev.test226825.ep2)

test226889 (test.env.dev.os.wn.sev.test226889.ep2)

test227082 (test.env.dev.os.wn.sev.test227082.ep2)

test227102 (test.env.dev.os.wn.sev.test227102.ep2)

test227159 (test.env.dev.os.wn.sev.test227159.ep2)

test227203 (test.env.dev.os.wn.sev.test227203.ep2)

But would like to have a regular expression so that my output looks like below, basically to remove the brackets/parenthesis. Any help would be much appreciated.

test226693 test.env.dev.os.wn.sev.test226693.ep2

test226745 test.env.dev.os.wn.sev.test226745.ep2

test226825 test.env.dev.os.wn.sev.test226825.ep2

test226889 test.env.dev.os.wn.sev.test226889.ep2

test227082 test.env.dev.os.wn.sev.test227082.ep2

test227102 test.env.dev.os.wn.sev.test227102.ep2

test227159 test.env.dev.os.wn.sev.test227159.ep2

test227203 test.env.dev.os.wn.sev.test227203.ep2

Comment: Is there any reason for not to use `i.replace('(', '')` and `i.replace(')', '')`?

Comment: try with `of(?:\s(\w+)\s\((.*?)\))`, group 1 and group 2 will give the result you are looking for.

Comment: Try this : re.sub(r"[\([{})\]]", "", text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your regex expression. You can check them for example using [/regex101.com](https://regex101.com/).
In your case you create on big group inside your match containing the
`testXXXXX (test.env.dev.os.wn.sev.testXXXXXX.ep2)`.

What you want to do instead is creating a group for each substring you need. The regex would be something like `of\s(\w+)\s\((.*?)\)`.

Now you just need to handle that res is a list of list, so join the lists and you get the output you want.

```py
pattern=re.compile(r'of\s(\w+)\s\((.*?)\)')
res=pattern.findall(txt)
for i in res:
    print(' '.join(i))
```

Note: posted at the same time as @simpleApp commented :)